# How to bring up an okay / cancel dialog box in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dialog

When I click on "delete post" on StackOverflow it brings up a window on the screen asking if I want to go ahead or if I want to cancel.

How can I do that in Javascript so that it will work in both a computer and on an IPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `confirm`, use the code as below:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
confirm("Press a button!");
}
</script>
```

The above example is very basic, if you some designed confirm box then please check [craftpip's jquery-confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) Hope you like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `confirm` for this. It will return `true` or `false` depending on the user's action. Example:

```
var result = confirm("Please confirm this action!")
if(result)
    //The user confirmed the action
else
    //The user declined the action
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated by others, use the `confirm` method.

You can get the callback from confirm like this:

```
confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?", function(result) {
if(result)
    doSomethingPositive();
else
    doSomethingNegative();
});
```

Comment: 1) don't repeat answers other people have already given unless you have something to add. 2) this is not how you use `confirm()`

Comment: @yourmom whats wrong with this method? When I created my answer there were no examples with callback inovked

Comment: The confirm method does not have any callbacks. It simply returns true or false depending on user action.